# No view for id for fragment

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I'm trying to use le lib SlidingMenu in my app but i'm having some problems.
I'm getting this error:

> 11-04 15:50:46.225: E/FragmentManager(21112): No view found for id
>   0x7f040009 (com.myapp:id/menu_frame) for fragment
>   SampleListFragment{413805f0 #0 id=0x7f040009}

BaseActivity.java

```
package com.myapp;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity;

public class BaseActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {
    private int mTitleRes;
    protected ListFragment mFrag;

    public BaseActivity(int titleRes) {
        mTitleRes = titleRes;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setTitle(mTitleRes);

        // set the Behind View
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            mFrag = new SampleListFragment();
            t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
            t.commit();
        } else {
            mFrag = (ListFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.menu_frame);
        }

        // customize the SlidingMenu
        SlidingMenu slidingMenu = getSlidingMenu();
        slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        slidingMenu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_shadow_width);
        slidingMenu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.slidingmenu_shadow);
        slidingMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        slidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.slidingmenu);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                    toggle();
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.myapp.SampleListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</fragment>
```

menu_frame.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

SampleListFragment.java

```
package com.myapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SampleListFragment extends ListFragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity());
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            adapter.add(new SampleItem("Sample List", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));
        }
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class SampleItem {
        public String tag;
        public int iconRes;
        public SampleItem(String tag, int iconRes) {
            this.tag = tag; 
            this.iconRes = iconRes;
        }
    }

    public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SampleItem> {

        public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, 0);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
            icon.setImageResource(getItem(position).iconRes);
            TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
            title.setText(getItem(position).tag);

            return convertView;
        }

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.myapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import beans.Tweet;

import database.DatabaseHelper;

import adapters.TweetListViewAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    public MainActivity(){
        super(R.string.app_name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_tweets);

        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = db.getAllTweets();

        TweetListViewAdapter adapter = new TweetListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, tweets);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        setSlidingActionBarEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the view menu_frame is not found because I have a view with the id menu_frame and this view is a child of the layout menu_frame.

Comment: apparently menu_frame is a framelayout, not a fragment. That's probably why it is bot found as a fragment.

Comment: @njzk2 - FrameLayouts are used as containers for Fragments that are added at runtime (which is how they are adding the fragment). Normally this error means that you try to call replace/remove on a fragment using a layout ID that does not exist in the layout that is inflated. They are not calling setContentView so this view ID does not exist. I'm not sure how setBehindContentView works in the library that's being used but according to a quick google search setContentView also needs to be called (since setBehindContentView  doesn't replace it).

Comment: Even if I put `setContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);` before `setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);` the problem is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setBehindContentView()` is used to set the layout of the `SlidingMenu`.

```
    /**
     * Set the behind view content to an explicit view.
     * This view is placed directly into the behind view 's view hierarchy.
     * It can itself be a complex view hierarchy.
     *
     * @param view The desired content to display.
     * @param layoutParams Layout parameters for the view. (unused)
     */
    public void setBehindContentView(View view, LayoutParams layoutParams) {
            mViewBehind = view;
            mSlidingMenu.setMenu(mViewBehind);
    }
```

However, since in the `BaseActivity` you called `slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.slidingmenu);`, the menu layout will be overwritten to `R.layout.slidingmenu`. Hence, `R.layout.menu_frame` is not inflated and the ID cannot be found.

Try to remove either `setBehindContentView()` or `setMenu()`.

Comment: Thanks, I remove this line `slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.slidingmenu);` and now it's work ;)