# how to execute new SlidingMenu(this) only once to implement SlidingMenu?

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I follow [SlidingMenu Example](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu#simple-example) to create a sliding menu:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ......

        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.activity_fragment);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
          .beginTransaction()
          .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new MenuFragment())
          .commit();
    }
}
```

**It works.**
But this will execute `new SlidingMenu(this)` **everytime** when navigation to this activity.
I want to create SlidingMenu **only once** for this activtiy, so

### The first modify try:

```
  private static SlidingMenu sSlidingMenu;
    ......
    if (sSlidingMenu == null) {
      sSlidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    }
    sSlidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);     
    sSlidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.activity_fragment);
    ......
```

It works when executed first time, but **it crash second time:**

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: This SlidingMenu appears to already be attached

I google this error tip, and found these similar questions:

[Q1 StackoverFlow: This SlidingMenu appears to already be attached Androd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779814/this-slidingmenu-appears-to-already-be-attached-androd)

[Q2 Github: Fix for changing content view after SlidingMenu is attached to the Activity. #324](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/pull/324)

then try

### The Second modify try:

```
    ......
    if (sSlidingMenu == null) {
      sSlidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
      sSlidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);     
    }
    sSlidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.activity_fragment);

    getSupportFragmentManager()
      .beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new MenuFragment())
      .commit();
```

It also crash when execute second time:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **No view found for id 0x7f090035 (:id/fragmentContainer) for fragment MenuFragment**

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770481/no-view-for-id-for-fragment)

*I have no idea how to execute `new SlidingMenu(this)` only once to implement SlidingMenu. Please help,  thanks.*